# SQL not working when I choose some fields from the 1st table

Tags: mysql

I just used this code, and working properly with me:

```
SELECT
* FROM `order` as o
LEFT JOIN `services` as s ON s.`id` = o.`service_id`
LEFT JOIN `users` as u ON u.`id` = o.`users_id`
LEFT JOIN `files` as f ON f.`order_id` = o.`id`
```

but when I try to choose some fields from the 1st table, the results not showing the other tables

```
SELECT
    o.`id` AS `id`,
    o.`service_id`,
    o.`extras`,
    o.`quantity`,
    o.`price`,
    o.`links`,
    o.`keywords`,
    o.`status_id`,
    o.`users_id`,
    o.`date`,
    o.`notes`,
    o.`c_reason`,
    o.`agent_star`
FROM `order` as o
LEFT JOIN `services` as s ON s.`id` = o.`service_id`
LEFT JOIN `users` as u ON u.`id` = o.`users_id`
LEFT JOIN `files` as f ON f.`order_id` = o.`id`
```

I don't know what is the exact error on the 2nd code, I need to show all columns from the tables: services, users & files
all columns or just defined columns

Comment: Are you saying you want to see columns form the other tables? Like `s.*, u.*, f.*`?

Comment: Can you add more context?. Does the second query run or does it give you an specific error?

Comment: yes that's right, I need to also show s.*, u.*, f.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is working for me, thanks everybody :)

```
SELECT
    o.`id` AS `id`,
    o.`service_id`,
    o.`extras`,
    o.`quantity`,
    o.`price`,
    o.`links`,
    o.`keywords`,
    o.`status_id`,
    o.`users_id`,
    o.`date`,
    o.`notes`,
    o.`c_reason`,
    o.`agent_star`
    s.*
    u.*
    f.*
FROM `order` as o
LEFT JOIN `services` as s ON s.`id` = o.`service_id`
LEFT JOIN `users` as u ON u.`id` = o.`users_id`
LEFT JOIN `files` as f ON f.`order_id` = o.`id`
```

Answer (score 0):

You when you select * from a join you are selecting all results from all tables involved.

When you are specifying orders you are only getting the results as they pertain to the orders table you get the same thing if you were to do SELECT o.* so if you want to see shared fields from different tables you have to specify them in your select statement as well.

Basically you're seeing the Different between SELECT * and SELECT o.*

Comment: but If I use o.* I can not make o.id as id, also I think it's better to define the exact records that I need. the problem is how to get all fields from the other tables?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see this earlier but yes you can still call a column whatever you want so you can still say o.id as id. The line where I said if you want to see share fields from different tables you have to specify them in your select statement as well. Your end result was exactly what I was referring to. Glad you got it all working how you needed it.